# How do you convert a JS array into a PHP array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I would like to convert a JS array to a PHP array. I tried to send the value to the PHP page:

```
var seatsReserved = [];

function reserve(seat) {
    seat.setAttribute("class", "reserved");
    var hasClass = seat.classList.contains('reserved');
    if (hasClass) {
        seatsReserved.push(parseInt(seat.innerHTML));
        $.post('../index.php', {
            'seatsReserved': seatsReserved
        });
        console.log(seatsReserved.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b
        }));
    }
}
```

However, when I run

```
$seatsReserved = $_POST['seatsReserved'];
```

I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: seatsReserved

How can I correctly pass the array to PHP?

Comment: you need to serialize array into string `JSON.stringify(seatsReserved)`

Comment: Look at the Network tab in your browser. You can see what is actually sent there. jQuery might not encode/format it correctly.

Comment: Btw: how do you know what the server says? You're not listening for a response....

Comment: `$.post('../index.php', { 'seatsReserved': JSON.stringify(seatsReserved) });` is it the correct way to serialize and send it?

Comment: Yup, that looks good. Then on the server you need to use json_decode to convert it into a PHP array.

Comment: `$seatsReserved = json_decode($_POST['seatsReserved']);` I used this function but I still get the error: `Undefined index seatsReserved`

Comment: Convert it into json before you send it out. and inside php, you can convert the json into php array by json_decode($_POST['seatsReserved'])